# determining aggregate root in MyProducts and ebay and amazon listings

Tags: c#, dns, domain-driven-design, aggregate

Should I make listings part of the MyProduct aggregate or should they be aggregate roots.

If I make it part of MyProduct aggregate then i loose the ability to persist listings independently of MyProduct. On the other hand I dont see how I can have a listing without a MyProduct and therefore should be part of MyProduct aggregate.

Should ebay and amazon listing be a value objects or entities.

Comment: It depends on what kind of listing it is. Could you give an example?

Comment: on ebay we have variation listings (MANY MyProduct to ONE listing) but also a MyProduct can be listed in multiple marketplaces (ONE MyProduct to MANY listings) therefore i see the relationship between them as Many-to-Many.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience with ecommerce product catalogs, you typically have multiple listings per product to represent product variations for example. Ultimately, both a listing and the corresponding product should be aggregates. This doesn't mean that you can't enforce a constraint that a listing must be associated with a product. It only means that instead of a direct object reference you will use an identity reference to express the relationship. Behaviors on listings are typically independent from behaviors on the corresponding product. If there is a dependency, it can be propagated in an eventually consistent manner.

Take a look at [Effective Aggregate Design](http://dddcommunity.org/library/vernon_2011/) for more on this.

Comment: where do you think i should place logic that maps a listing from my model to a listing as defined in ebay and amazon schemas files. Should this be domain logic or infrastructure logic.

Comment: that should be in organization specific modules. so you'd have an amazon module which adapts your local domain model to amazon's. in DDD parlance this is called an ACL - anti-corruption layer.